# Kodi loads on ubuntu 14.04 but doesn't open

Tags: kodi

Latest Kodi (xbmc) was installed/uninstalled/re-installed several times.
Whenever I'm trying to open it nothing happens (no error messages), although using the alt-tab application switcher I can see Kodi's icon (indicating it's running).
Can anyone help me?
Thanks.

Comment: Two questions: 1. How did you install Kodi? 2. What is the output if you run kodi from a terminal with `kodi`?

Comment: Eventually, I managed to resolve the problem fiddling with ubuntu's display settings. 
Thanks.

Comment: You may want to consider sharing your experience with an own answer. It may help people who come here with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Go to
Accesories/ File manager -
.kodi -
User data -
Database - 
Then delete textures13.db from the file
Worked for me